# setting up android on ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, kivy, android-sdk-tools

I have followed all the steps given in [this](http://python-for-android.readthedocs.org/en/latest/prerequisites/)
and [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2302780)

still when I run:

```
./distribute.sh -m "kivy"
```

I gets this error:

```
Entering in ARM enviromnent
Unable to find compiler (arm-linux-androideabi-gcc) !!
1. Ensure that SDK/NDK paths are correct
2. Ensure that you've the Android API 14 SDK Platform (via android tool)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error relates to setting the paths to the android sdk and ndk. The relevant section of the linked doc is:

```
export ANDROIDSDK=/path/to/android-sdk
export ANDROIDNDK=/path/to/android-ndk
export ANDROIDNDKVER=rX
export ANDROIDAPI=X

# example
export ANDROIDSDK="/home/tito/code/android/android-sdk-linux_86"
export ANDROIDNDK="/home/tito/code/android/android-ndk-r7"
export ANDROIDNDKVER=r7
export ANDROIDAPI=14
```

Are you certain that you did this correctly? To check, what is the output of `echo $ANDROIDSDK` and `echo $ANDROIDNDK` in the terminal that you're using.